# How can I binding a style to Controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to make blinking style fro Image, and I intend to assign this style dynamically and assign this style for some image that has dependency property HasError, when HasErro=True the image blinking otherwise not blinking and style set to null.

here is my style that works correctly:

```
<Style x:Key="myImageAnimateStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                           BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                           From="1.0" To="0.0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and this is my style binding:

```
<Image x:Name="imgErro" Style="{Binding HasError, Converter={StaticResource ErrorBooleanAnimate}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
```

and this is my Value converter with two solution but doesn't work:

```
    public class ErrorBooleanAnimate : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool?))
            return null;

        if ((bool)value == true)
        {
            // Solution 1
            //return "{DynamicResource myImageAnimateStyle}";

            // Solution 2
            Style newStyle = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource("myImageAnimateStyle");
            return newStyle;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

what is the best solution for this issue?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I get no Error but It doesn't work as I expect. I expect which image has error start to blink and another image doesn't blink, but all of them doesn't blink.

Comment: Are you sure you defined `ErrorBooleanAnimate` in the  resources?

Comment: <local:ErrorBooleanAnimate x:Key="ErrorBooleanAnimate"/>

Comment: What is type of `HasError`? `bool?` or `bool`?

Comment: its nullable bool?

Comment: Ok and where is resource defined? Under userControl resources or App resources?

Comment: Under the UserControl

Comment: <UserControl.Resources>
          <local:ErrorBooleanAnimate x:Key="ErrorBooleanAnimate"/>
 </UserControl.Resources>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **define resource under App resources** to make your code work.

Still if you want to define it under UserControl resources, you need to pass userControl instance to converter and search in it's resources.

```
(Style)userControl.TryFindResource("myImageAnimateStyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the style to the converter:

```
<Image Style="{Binding HasError,
                       Converter={StaticResource ErrorBooleanAnimate},
                       ConverterParameter={StaticResource myImageAnimateStyle},
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Just return `parameter` in the converter.